# assert to check after memset in C

Tags: c

I have a `void* ptr` and I am doing `memset` for it, later I am trying to check if it has been set to 0 using `assert()` but I am getting `Assertion ptr == 0 failed`

```
void* ptr = malloc(100);
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));

assert(ptr == 0);
```

Comment: `sizeof(ptr));`is the size of a pointer: 4 or 8 bytes, probably. `assert(ptr == 0); `checks if ptr is NULL (which it is not, unless malloc failed)

Comment: 'ptr' is a memory address. When you call memset, you set some bytes at that address to 0. But the address itself won't be 0. If you want to set the address itself to 0, you need memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof ptr). But then that would be a memory leak. You probably want to assert something like (*(int *)ptr == 0).

Comment: If you want to set the pointer to 0 it would be `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));`. If you want to set the memory pointed to to 0 it would be `memset(ptr, 0, 100); assert(*ptr == 0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue you're running into is that `void*` pointer does not carry any information along with it about the type of data at the end of a pointer. An `int*` pointer or a pointer to an object instance would carry additional information. However the compiler doesn't know how big the object is at the other end of the pointer, nor does it know how to dereference the pointer.

Instead, you need to do something like the following:

```
void* ptr = malloc(100);
memset(ptr, 0, 100); // sizeof(ptr) == 4 or 8 (32-bit or 64-bit), so you can't use sizeof() here
int* iptr = (int*)ptr; // We tell the compiler that the values at the end of the pointer should be interpreted as integers
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    assert(iptr[i] == 0);
}
```

### Edit

It occurred to me after posting this that `int` is more than 1 byte, so this would actually assert on too many bytes. You only allocated 100, and we're checking 400 here.

Instead of converting your `void*` to an `int*`, you should convert to a `char*` or similar 1-byte type (or have the for loop only run from 0 to 25 -- but that's just confusing)

### Edit 2 - A Quick Lesson on Pointers

I realize upon looking at my code and the code others have posted that most colleges do a terrible job of teaching pointers, which leads to a lot of confusion. So I thought this minor addendum might help.

First, the basics: You probably already know that data is written to RAM. Normally WHERE it's written in RAM isn't ***too*** important, so long as you remember where it is. If I were keeping a running sum in the 103rd "slot" in memory, then I just have to remember to keep adding to the 103rd slot. When you name a variable in C/C++, the compiler picks a random and unused space in memory. You're effectively creating a human-readable name for that space. So if I say `int a = 5;`, the compiler picks a random spot in memory (maybe the 78th slot) and then whenever I say `a` in my code, the compiler knows that I'm referring to the 78th slot in memory.

Note that the **compiler** knows I'm referring to the 78th slot in memory. This means that the `a` in my source code gets replaced with a reference to the 78th slot in memory when the code is compiled, and the actual assembly code that is produced looks something like:

```
// Code:
int a = 5;
a = a + 1;
int b = a;

// Compiles to (this may be invalid x86 assembly - it just serves as an example):
mov 78, 5 -- move the value "5" to memory address 78
add [78], 1, 78 -- add the value stored in memory address 78 and 1, then store the result in memory address 78
mov 79, [78] -- move the value stored in memory address 78 to memory address 79
```

Notice how the compiled code references memory addresses directly. This is what the compiler saves us from by allowing us to assign a name to a variable.

With a **pointer**, instead of storing data into RAM, we store a memory address into RAM - then we have to check this memory address to find the real data. It would be like if you went to your friend's house at 123 Street Road and found a note on the door saying "Sorry, I moved. You can find me at 987 Boulevard Avenue". So then you go to 987 Boulevard Avenue and have a fun party with your friend. Because that's his **real** address.

There are many reasons we might use a pointer. I'll gloss over the possible reasons for using them, because all that matters is that you know what they do and how they work. So when we create a pointer, once again the compiler is keeping track of a slot in memory and we're giving it a human readable name. So when you say `int* a = new int;`, the compiler picks a random unused spot in memory (maybe the 823rd slot) and whenever you say `a` in your code, the compiler knows that you're referring to the 823rd slot. **However**, what's actually stored in the 823rd slot is **not** the integer you're looking for -- it's a memory address where you can find the integer you really want.

There are three helpful operators to remember when dealing with pointers:

- `*`: The indirection operation (which I recently learned is also called the dereference operator). This tells the compiler "follow the pointer". So if you had an `int*` called `a` then `*a` would say "what is the value of the integer located in the memory address stored in a?" (confusing, I know)
- `&`: I guess this would be called the "reference" operator? I always just called it the "memory address operator". If you pass a variable to this operator, it will return the location in memory where that variable is stored. This is useful if you want to create a pointer to a variable you already have
- `[]`: The offset operator. This tells the compiler that instead of going to the memory location referenced in the pointer, go to a place in memory **just past** that. It'd be like if you look at that "just moved" note at your friend's house and instead of visiting his new house, you went to the house 3 doors down. This is very useful when dealing with arrays. We store 20 integers in memory in a row. You have a pointer to the first integer, and all others integers are just an offset from that first one (`[1]` is a single integer after the starting one, `[2]` is two integers after the starting one, etc)

Note that the offset operator can only work if it knows the size of the object at the end of the pointer. `[1]` means to go one byte further in memory if you're pointing to an array of 1-byte objects. `[1]` means to go 8 bytes further in memory if you're pointing to an array of 8-byte objects. This is why `int*` and `long*` are different. They're both pointers (so they're both just an integer pointing to a place in memory) but when you use the offset operator the compiler will jump different amounts based on the type of variable.

`void*`, on the other hand, has **no** type information. You're literally telling the compiler that it should have no clue what's at the other end of that pointer. There are times when this is useful, but it generally just makes code harder since it takes all of the work the compiler does for you and forces the programmer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if ptr is null or not, but your intention is to check value at ptr should be zero, I assume.

try this

```
assert(*((int *)ptr) == 0);
```

Comment: This would work without throwing an error, however this only checks that the first 4 bytes at the end of the pointer are 0 (it follows the pointer, reads one int, and compares). This does not check all 100 bytes.

Comment: yes that's true, in that case we need to check all 100 bytes using loop. I just proposed a hint not whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the code line-by-line:

```
void* ptr = malloc(100);
```

You declared the pointer `ptr`, allocated 100 bytes and pointed `ptr` to it.

```
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
```

`sizeof(ptr)` is the size of your pointer, not the allocated memory where it is pointing. On most machines, this would just be 4 bytes, meaning you're initializing the first 4 bytes as 0 and the rest of the 100-byte allocated memory would just be garbage data. I mention this because this might not be what you want to do.

```
assert(ptr == 0);
```

This is your main question. If malloc failed, `ptr` would be 0, and it would have gotten an error when `memset` got called. If it didn't, then the pointer would be non-zero, and the assertion would fail since you're asserting that it should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr == 0` checks whether the pointer is pointing to `NULL`, it doesn't check
whether the contents pointed to by `ptr` are 0. So you have to check byte by byte if
the contents are 0.

The second problem is:

```
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
```

`sizeof` does **not** return the amount of bytes you've allocated, it returns
the size of a pointer. In you case you are only setting the first 8 bytes to 0
(assuming that on your target architecture the size of a pointer is 8).

You have to do

```
memset(ptr, 0, 100);
```

Because you only have a `void*` pointer, you would need to cast it to `char*` or
`unsigned char*` for processing the values. You are only checking against 0, so in this case 
signed/unsigned doesn't matter. You have to do:

```
// avoid hardcoding numbers, use variables instead
size_t len = 100;

void *ptr = malloc(len);

if(ptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    return 0; // or whatever, do not continue
}

memset(ptr, 0, len);

char *base = ptr;
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    // checking byte by byte if 0
    assert(base[i] == 0);
}
```